# How to set image on pushbutton using client bundle in gwt

Tags: gwt

I am using client bundle in gwt.Using client bundle set image on label,open pdf and text file but how to set image in button ar pushbutton.
thankyou for reply....

Comment: using client bundle set image on push button.Thanx for reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using images on buttons is easy if you're using [com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CustomButton](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.java).

Creating a button with an image:

```java
CustomButton button = new PushButton(new Image(resources.logo1()));
```

To change the image, set a new one on the Button's up face:

```java
button.getUpFace().setImage(new Image(resources.logo2()));
```